# Oiling/greasing a garage door

Tags: lubrication, garage-door

My garage door is very loud. I sprayed all of the metal-on-metal moving portions of the garage door (except the Genie screw drive track) with WD-40 as they all have some small degree of rust. This helped quite a bit, but I would like to do more.

I know WD-40 is probably not the right lubricant, so my question is: what is the correct lubricant for the various parts of a garage door, including the screw drive in my Genie garage door opener?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Genie makes a [lubricant](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?storeId=10051&productId=100665696&langId=-1&catalogId=10053&ci_sku=100665696&ci_src=14110944&cm_mmc=shopping-_-googlebase-_-D30X-_-100665696&locStoreNum=4647) specifically designed for their screw drive openers.  I used it at my old house and it seemed to work fairly well. You can buy it any major home centers.  I believe they came in packs of 3 tubes and each tube was designed for one lubrication.  I lubricated mine about every 6 months.

Comment: PB Blaster also makes garage door/chain lube. Works good.

Answer (score 1):

Use a grease or a grease-like spray. I'm a big fan of white lithium grease. It comes in tubes and spray form.

If you use a lube like the Genie brand, read the label or get the MSDS for it. Odds are good that its the same thing as more generic product and you can save some money buying off brand.